# Install and configure samba with OpenLDAP

Tags: openldap, samba

I am trying to install and configure samba, (I already installed and configurated LDAP). I am following this [tutorial](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/samba-ldap.html), the problem is I get this error:

> **adding new entry "cn={14}samba,cn=schema,cn=config" ldap_add: Insufficient access (50)**

when I try to execute this command:

> **sudo ldapadd -Q -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -f cn\=samba.ldif**

I did many searches on the internet but I didn't find a solution. Could you help me?

Answer (score 0):

The ACI you are using do not permit the authorization state of the connection to add that entry. BIND using a DN that has authorization to add the entry.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the reply.What is the ACI? How can I use a DN that has authorization to add entry?